# import in javascript: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to import a function in my file in node, but I get the error unexpected token. What am I doing wrong here?
My file works2.js looks like this

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

export default isEmpty
```

My test2.js file looks like this:

```
import isEmpty from './works2';
```

Both files are in the same directory, but if I execute test2.js I get the error:

import isEmpty from './works2';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Node does not support es6 modules without file extension. So import from `'./works2.js'`

Comment: @Ashish That's an old question that's no longer applicable for es6 modules

Comment: What is the version of node you are using?

Comment: Also, node assumes that the file is Commonjs (old-school node modules) if it ends with `.js`. If you want to write es6 modules the file must end in `.mjs` unless it's packaged along with it's own `package.json` in its own directory. Then it can end in `.js` if you define `"type" : "module"` in `package.json`

Comment: See: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @Ashish I reopened this question because the other question was specifically about node 5

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running node 10 or above, es6 modules are... not straightforward.

ES6 module specification does not support guessing of file extensions. Therefore, in order to comply with the specification node.js also does not automatically guess file extension. So your import statement **must** be the actual name of your file.

For example, if your file is named `works2` (without any extension) then you can do:

```
import isEmpty from './works2';
```

Otherwise, if you file is named `works2.js` you **must** do:

```
import isEmpty from './works2.js';
```

Secondly, due to incompatibility between how node modules are initialized and how the ECMAScript specification requires ES6 modules to be initialized you must specify that the module is an ES6 module.

There are generally two ways to do this:

1. Make sure that the nearest uplevel `package.json` file contains the following configuration:

   ```
   "type" : "module"
   ```

   This tells node.js to treat all files in in the `package.json` directory and below as es6 modules unless it ends in `.cjs`.
2. Give your file the `.mjs` extension. This tells node.js that the file is an es6 module:

   ```
   import isEmpty from './works2.mjs';
   ```

> Note: In the early days of ES6 module discussions it looked like it may be possible to unify ES6 modules and Commonjs modules (indeed, a lot of inspiration for how ES6 modules work was informed by node.js). So a lot of projects like Babel and Typescript silently used ES6 import syntax with Commonjs modules. But browser vendors started implementing non-compatible behavior with their version of ES6 modules and the ECMAScript comittee, which historically have always written the spec to conform with most common browser implementations, made how ES6 modules work in browsers the standard. The compromises above is node developer's attempt to support ES6 modules without throwing away the millions of lines of code on NPM